# select list by specific id using two models in one view- Asp.Net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, relationship

Classes

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.SubCategories = new HashSet<SubCategory>();
    }               
    public int Cat_id { get; set; }
    public string Cat_Name { get; set; }
    public string Cat_Desc { get; set; }                
    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCat_id { get; set; }
    public byte SubCat_icon { get; set; }
    public string SubCat_Name { get; set; }
    public string SubCat_Desc { get; set; }
    public int Cat_id { get; set; }                 
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<object> myModel = new List<object>();
    myModel.Add(db.Categories.ToList());
    myModel.Add(db.SubCategories.ToList());
    return View(myModel);
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<object>
@{
    List<ProjName.Models.Category> IstCategory = Model.ToList()[0] as List<ProjName.Models.Category>;
    List<ProjName.Models.SubCategory> IstSubCategory = Model.ToList()[1] as List<ProjName.Models.SubCategory>;        
}
<h1>Category</h1>
@foreach(var item in IstCategory)
{           
    <div>@item.Cat_Name</div><br />      
}
<hr />
<h1>SubCategory</h1>
@foreach(var item in IstSubCategory)
{     
    <div>@item.SubCat_Name</div><br />       
}
```

How to pass distinct/specific id in foreach() loop and where condition, when data is selected in list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve this? Each Category has its SubCategories list.

```
<h1>Category</h1>
@foreach(var cat in IstCategory)
{           
   <div>@cat.Cat_Name</div><br />   

   <hr />
   <h1>SubCategory</h1>
   @foreach(var sub_cat in IstSubCategory.Where(s => s.Cat_id == cat.Cat_id))
   {      
     <div>@sub_cat.SubCat_Name</div><br />       
   }     
}
```